# Continue working it through or start over?

Tags: planning

I'm writing a novel, but due to lack of time because these years for me are very important for my academic future, it hasn't progressed that much. However, I like it very much and would like to finish it, plus I have invested a lot of time into editing and the like. The entire plot is ready with the exception of a few minor conflict kinks, and I have a trilogy planned.

However, I'm the type of writer that gets struck with other inspirations, and currently I just got hit with one I'm itching to write--an 8 book series in which the entire plot for the first book is also planned out; yep, I got reaaally into it.

Should I stick it out and work harder on the original project? That's what I lean to; I ought to finish the trilogy first. But at the same time, I find myself sketching the character designs for my other inspiration...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you writing for fun and to relax after your job? Then follow your inspiration as David Roberts suggests. But do not expext to ever finish a book, because very likely what you perceive as inspiration is the joy in dreaming up stories coupled with an unwillingness to do the less pleasant parts of a writer's job.

Or are you writing to publish? Then finish one book -- not one trilogy; one book! -- before you start on the next. Note down ideas you have for the next book, so you won't forget them (and can free your mind), but don't explore them. As explained elsewhere (in other answers on this site), a good time to start the next book is when the first is being reviewed by beta readers, but that is the most overlap that is not detrimental to finishing a project. Discipline, I believe, is the key to success.

But, as I never tire of emphasizing, people are different. Maybe you can work on – and actually make progress in – multiple parallel projects. Maybe you know the kind of person you are, or you'll have to try and find out.

Comment: Thank you for your response! It's given me the affirmation that I should discipline myself and push on.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the best time to write is when the inspiration is active and flowing on its own.  If you've got thoughts and images pressing to the front of your brain and the words and outlines are presenting themselves - write them down!  Don't put it off.  Then, when the urgency to work on your 8 book series begins to wane, switch gears back to the novel you're currently writing and push to finish it up.  Also, the break might allow your subconscious some breathing room to work out the "kinks" on its own.

Answer (score 0):

For me, personally, the most exciting point of any project is the initial burst of inspiration, and my interest always wanes near the end.  So when I start any project, I always need to make a personal commitment to finish it, or else I end up with all starts, and no finished projects.